# creating a trigger to update a date in a table before a specific value is changed

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I am tryign to create a trigger which will update a table so that when something is inserted into the table the given end date will change to set to the day before the start date of the new entry.   i have created this trigger which complies but when checking it doesn't work. can anyone see the porblem with it?

```
CREATE TRIGGER
    updatetrigger12345
BEFORE INSERT ON
    shares_amount
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
        UPDATE OF
          shares_amount
        SET
          date_end = :NEW.date_start-1
        WHERE
          share_issue_id = :NEW.share_issue_id
          AND
          share_id= :NEW.share_id
          ;
END
;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

Bad, bad, bad.  You do not want to attempt to update the table on whose trigger is being executed.  You just need to update the ":new" fields of interest.  Maybe something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER
    updatetrigger12345
BEFORE INSERT ON
    shares_amount
FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN

  :NEW.date_end := :NEW.date_start-1;
END
;
/
```

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/triggers/before_update.php).  In addition, I would try to really stay away from using trigger if not needed.  There certainly are situations when they make sense; however, they can be abused and cause a lot of confusion and problems down the road. Please read this classic AskTom article [The Trouble With Triggers](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-sep/o58asktom-101055.html).